# HP ink tank 410 series wireless support for ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, printing, hplip

I tried using hplip-3.19.11.run file for installing my ink tank 410 series, but the installer is not able to detect the printer wirelessly.
Ubuntu native cups, is able to find the printer on the wireless network, but when I give any print command it complains for communication error.
While printer when connected via USB, is able to print from ubuntu 18.04.
Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure is it related or not but you need to install proprietary/binary driver/plugin for [your printer](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) - try `hp-plugin`.

Comment: Hi Norbert, tried that but it seems hp-plugin is also not helping in communicating with the printer over wireless.  Hoping either HP looks this up or some god from linux community help us.